# Which tool has replaced gatttool in bluez5?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, pybluez

It seems like since `commit b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617`
`gatttool` has been deprecated but I'm unable to find any information on
what has replaced gattool.

Every Python Bluetooth LE packages I looked into relays on gatttool
and is now broken on my ArchLinux system since the bluez package isn't
build with `--enabled-deprecated` flag (which would build gatttool binary).

`pygatt` is just broken on my system and `bluepy` doesn't build as they
ship there own (on my system broken) bluez code to build gatttool.

Whatsoever I looking to write a new wrapper around whatever replaced
gatttool but I'm unable to find any information on this topic.

So which tool from the bluez stack can I use to write a new Python Bluetooth LE wrapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update**

[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Troubleshooting) listed `gatttool` as deprecated and lists [`btgatt-client`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt) the D-Bus Gatt API as replacement.

[gattlib from labapart](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib) supports `bluez` <strike>5</strike> and provides [`gatttool`](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib/tree/master/examples/gatttool).

I guess gatttool got deprecated due to a missing maintainer rather than being replaced by some new tool.

**edit**
unfortunately the code for gatttool in the linked repository supports only bluez 4.

Comment: In [gattlib](https://github.com/labapart/gattlib), you can use `gatttool` for Bluez v5. I (as the author of gattlib) extend `gatttool` to use gattlib API.

Comment: thanks for letting me/us know. That looks promissing

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but this package:

https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib

describes itself thusly:

> This is a Python library to use the GATT Protocol for Bluetooth LE
>   devices. It is a wrapper around the implementation used by gatttool in
>   bluez package. It does not call other binaries to do its job :)

Since I want to access GATT functions from Python, I'm about to give it a whirl.